# Add list elements to dict values

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I'm learning python and having a hard time with this code. I need to update every dict key value with the elements in the list. The list and dict will always have the same length.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dict = {2433: 0, 2429: 0, 2425: 0, 2423: 0, 2427: 0}
```

Expected output:

```
dict = {2433: 1, 2429: 2, 2425: 3, 2423: 4, 2427: 5}
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you want to create a dictionary from a list of keys (or a dummy dictionary) and a list of values?

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dct = {2433: 0, 2429: 0, 2425: 0, 2423: 0, 2427: 0}

new_dct = dict(zip(dct, lst))
```

output: `{2433: 1, 2429: 2, 2425: 3, 2423: 4, 2427: 5}`

*NB. do not use `list` and `dict` as variable names, those are python builtins*